# Difference between address.code and type(Contract).runtimeCode in solidity

Tags: solidity

Can anyone please clear my doubt about the difference between [address.code](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=address%20initial#members-of-address-types) and [type(Contract).runtimeCode](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=type#type-information) in solidity. Shouldn't they be same.

Answer (score 4):

They have very little in common, actually.

`address.code` is done on chain, it corresponds to the EXTCODECOPY opcode, and  it allows you to retrieve the code stored at an address (i.e, a deployed contract).

`type(Contract).runtimeCode` is  done by the compiler, it doesnt load the code from an arbitrary address, it computes the runtime code of a contract definition *it knows* (that is in your imports or in your contract file)

Comment: But why the resultant bytecodes are different since both get the bytecode excluding init code ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the two

`address.code` gives the code stores at the account belonging to *address*.
This could be any address (EOA's will return zero as they don't contain any code). For this, the address needs to exist on the blockchain.

`type(Contract).runtimeCode` takes in a contract and computes the runtime code of the contract. Since this only computes it based on the contract definition, the contract doesn't have to be on the mainnet.

Comment: I noticed a difference in the resultant bytecodes. Why so ?

Comment: @Xirexor could be a number of reasons. Two most obvious that comes to mind are different compiler version/flags, and immutable variables initialized during contract construction. But could be anything else too

Comment: In general both return runtime code right ?